# Авторизация пользователей - сравнение пароля

Tags: php, php7

Делаю страницу для авторизации пользователей

1) Вот так у меня хешируется пароль при сохранении в бд

```
$hash_pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

2) При попытке пользователя зайти на сайт я для начала проверяю существует ли такой логин и потом уже в соответствии с логином  делаю второй запрос и получаю по этому логину пароль (логин уникальный)

```
$check_password = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = :mail');
$check_password->execute(['mail' => $mail]);
$hash = $check_password->fetchColumn();
```

3) После чего пытаюсь сравнить пароль введенный в форме с тем который получил по запросу в бд.
и вот тут то у меня проблемы, я проверял если не использую хеширования и сравниваю то все работает но при использовании алгоритмов хеширования ничего не получается.

```
password_verify($password, $hash)
```

все время возвращает false, помогите разобраться, как правильно сделать проверку пароля?

Comment: Надо взять и __глазами__ сравнить хеш возвращаемый из БД и хеш получаемый при вводе пароля.

Comment: @u_mulder сравнивал, разные почему то получаются , пароли точно одни и те-же, почему так получается понять не могу и проверка данных на обеих странице одинаковая так что ничего при проверке не может меняться.

Comment: попробуйте без базы данных. Получить хэш, потом проверить введённый пароль. И, кстати, не страшно что хэши каждый раз разные получаются

Comment: @ArchDemon  А как тогда проверять пароли если они при хэшировании разный результат дают, ведь в бд нельзя хранить не хешированые пароли.

Comment: `password_verify` с этим прекрасно справляется.

Comment: @ArchDemon раз вы говорите что мне нужно попробовать без БД, значит у меня меня может не работать что то именно из за БД?  но с запросами в бд все верно

Comment: Я не вижу как у вас происходит вставка нового пользователя в БД. И непонятно какие манипуляции вы проводите со вставляемыми данными.

Comment: какой размер колонки password в бд?

Comment: @KirillBabinec  varchar(50)

Comment: @СергейКузнецов Если прочитать выдержку из описания алгоритма PASSWORD_DEFAULT, то можно обнаружить такую строку: "В связи с этим рекомендуется выбирать длину поля для хранения в базе данных более 60 символов (255 символов могло быть хорошим вариантом).". Попробуйте увеличить длину колонки password до 255 (чтобы наверняка) и протестировать функционал еще раз.

Comment: @KirillBabinec спасибо огромное за помощь, теперь все работает, увеличил до 255 символов, как то сразу не дошло на это обратить внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто возможно столкнется с такой же проблемой, я указал слишком маленький размер   для колонки с паролем в БД, все заработало как только изменил его.